# Java DataOutputStream write and writeBytes have different behaviour when using python socket

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am experiencing some strange behaviour when sending TCP messages from a Java client to a python server, specifically there is a difference when using `write(byte[] b)` and `writeBytes(String s)`.

I am using the python server found [here](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html), with the buffer size set to 1024 (messages sent rarely exceed 100 bytes, and never are over 200):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
#
# Copyright (c) 2010 Doug Hellmann.  All rights reserved.
#
"""Server half of echo example.
"""
#end_pymotw_header

import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 39277)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            #print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break
    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

When I use `writeBytes(msg)`, the python server splits the message:

```
starting up on localhost port 39277
waiting for a connection
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53948)
received "$PNG"
received "VEST,LOCATION,1,144291"
received "1960"
received "50"
received "7,"
....
```

but when I convert the string to a byte array:

```
byte[] b = msg.getBytes();
DataOutputStream.write(b);
```

it doesn't split the message, and recieves a message as expected:

```
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53956)
received "$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1442912048641,,,,,,0"
received "$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1442912049655,51.55866171044861,-3.0430628338367187,0.0,1.25,148.87440204525353,0"
received "$PNGVEST,LOCATION,1,1442912050656,51.5586532525196,-3.043054619198384,0.0,1.25,148.87440290497682,0"
```

Why is this?

Comment: Your Python code looks wrong - `recv` is allowed to return as many bytes as it feels like, down to 1 or up to everything that's been sent.

Comment: @immibis what should I use instead? And why does this explain the different behaviour between the two methods?

Comment: You should keep calling recv until you've received the amount of data you want to receive.

Comment: The reason the behavior is different is most likely that the write-side buffering behavior for the two ways of writing are different.  Why?  Because the code is different, and (possibly) tuned for different use-cases.  But, frankly, it doesn't matter because the bug is on the reading end ...